# Golang HTTP REST mocking

Tags: rest, testing, go, mocking, integration-testing

I writing a client that connects to a server with REST endpoints. The client needs to make a chain of 11 different requests to complete an action (it's a [rococo](http://catb.org/jargon/html/R/rococo.html) backup system).

I'm writing my client in Go and I also want to write my mocks/tests in Go. What I'm unclear about is how a test called `func TestMain` would call into the client's `func main()`, to test completion of the chain of 11 requests.

My client's binary would be run from the shell in the following way:

`$ client_id=12345 region=apac3 backup`

How would I call `func main()` from the tests, with environment variables set? Or is there another approach? (I'm [comfortable writing tests](https://github.com/soniah/gosnmp/blob/master/marshal_test.go), so that's not the issue)

I'm looking at the Advanced Example in [jarcoal/httpmock](https://github.com/jarcoal/httpmock) (but I could use another library). At the end the example says `// do stuff that adds and checks articles`, is that where I would call `main()`?

I've pasted the Advanced Example below, for future reference.

---

```
func TestFetchArticles(t *testing.T) {
    httpmock.Activate()
    defer httpmock.DeactivateAndReset()

    // our database of articles
    articles := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)

    // mock to list out the articles
    httpmock.RegisterResponder("GET", "https://api.mybiz.com/articles.json",
        func(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
            resp, err := httpmock.NewJsonResponse(200, articles)
            if err != nil {
                return httpmock.NewStringResponse(500, ""), nil
            }
            return resp, nil
        },
    )

    // mock to add a new article
    httpmock.RegisterResponder("POST", "https://api.mybiz.com/articles.json",
        func(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
            article := make(map[string]interface{})
            if err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&article); err != nil {
                return httpmock.NewStringResponse(400, ""), nil
            }

            articles = append(articles, article)

            resp, err := httpmock.NewJsonResponse(200, article)
            if err != nil {
                return httpmock.NewStringResponse(500, ""), nil
            }
            return resp, nil
        },
    )

    // do stuff that adds and checks articles
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Writing this out helped me answer my own question.

`main()` would read in environment variables and then call a function like `doBackup(client_id, region)`. My test would mock the endpoints and then call `doBackup(client_id, region)`.